# find rowwise maxCoeff and Index of maxCoeff in Eigen

Tags: eigen

I want to find the maximum values and indices by row of a matrix. I based this on an example on the [eigen website](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html)  (example 7).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
    MatrixXf mat(2,4);
    mat << 1, 2, 6, 9,
           3, 1, 7, 2;

    MatrixXf::Index   maxIndex;

    VectorXf maxVal = mat.rowwise().maxCoeff(&maxIndex);

    std::cout << "Maxima at positions " << endl;
    std::cout << maxIndex << std::endl;
    std::cout << "maxVal " << maxVal << endl;
}
```

Problem here is that my line

```
    VectorXf maxVal = mat.rowwise().maxCoeff(&maxIndex);
```

is wrong. The original example has

```
    float maxNorm = mat.rowwise().sum().maxCoeff(&maxIndex);
```

i.e. there is an additional reduction .sum() involved. any suggestions? I guess I just want the eigen equivalent to what in matlab I would write as

```
[maxval maxind] = max(mymatrix,[],2)
```

i.e. find maximum value and it's index over the second dimension of mymatrix and return in a (nrow(mymatrix),2) matrix.
thanks!

(sent to the eigen list as well, sorry for cross-posting.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that this is not possible without using a for loop using the current api. As you said yourself, you can get the vector of maximum row values using

```
VectorXf maxVal = mat.rowwise().maxCoeff();
```

As far as I can tell from the API Documentation for [maxCoeff()](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a0b381dbcb0435c3a34a78abad4726cc3) it will only write back a single index value. Following code (untested) should give you what you want:

```
MatrixXf::Index   maxIndex[2];
VectorXf maxVal(2);
for(int i=0;i<2;++i)
    maxVal(i) = mat.row(i).maxCoeff( &maxIndex[i] );
```

Comment: hi jakob. yes, that's what i implemented in the meanwhile. thanks for your answer! I resorted to the eigen kde forum, since there don't seem to be many eigen users on SOF.

Comment: An option without using `MatrixXf::Index` would be  
 <code>int i, j;
s = vector.minCoeff(&i);        // s == vector[i]
s = matrix.maxCoeff(&i, &j);    // s == matrix(i,j)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I know this question is outdated, but could you please elaborate on how to use maxIndex[] once it is initialized with the relevant indices? The current documentation of Eigen does not offer valuable insights on how to proceed with the type Eigen::Index, to actually index a matrix, or at least I failed to do so.

Comment: Eigen::Index is an integer type. I would assume you can access the indexed element as `mat(i, maxIndex[i])`.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the "for loop" [solution by Jakob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11538208/148668), you could also use [libigl](https://github.com/libigl/libigl)'s `igl::mat_max` which functions like MATLAB's row-/column-wise max

```
Eigen::MatrixXf mat(2,4);
mat << 1, 2, 6, 9,
       3, 1, 7, 2;
Eigen::VectorXi maxIndices;
Eigen::VectorXf maxVals;
igl::mat_max(mat,2,maxVals,maxIndices);
```

Then `maxVals` would contain `[9;7]` and `maxIndices` would contain `[3;2]`.